# Store First Clicked Element in s Simple Memory Game

Tags: javascript, dom-events, click

I'm making a simple color memory game where originally there are 6 black boxes, and on click they change the color, taking the colors from a pre-defined array which gets shuffled at the start of the game.

But I've been stuck for hours at the comparison part - handleCardClick function. It works when the colors of two boxes are the same colors, however, when colors are different, only the second clicked box goes back to black, but the first one stays colored.

I can't seem to find a way to store the first clicked box. Maybe my approach is wrong in the essence. Here's my code:

```
    let colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue']
    const startButton = document.querySelector('.js-start-btn')
    const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.js-card')
    
    const shuffleArray = () => {
        var i = 0
          , j = 0
          , temp = null
      
        for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
          j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
          temp = array[i]
          array[i] = array[j]
          array[j] = temp
        }
    }
    
    
    let emptyArr = []
    
    const handleCardClik = () => {
        // Variable to store first click card
        let firstCard
        for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            cards[i]?.addEventListener('click', () => {
                cards[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i]
                firstCard = cards[i]
                //push colors into an empty array and start comparing them when there are two colors
                emptyArr.push(colors[i])
    
                if (emptyArr.length === 2) {
                // if colors are same apply them to the cards, clear the array and the storing variable    
                    if (emptyArr[0] === emptyArr[1]) {
                        firstCard = emptyArr[0]
                        cards[i].style.backgroundColor = emptyArr[1]
                        firstCard = ''
                        emptyArr = []
    
                // if colors differ keep them for 1 second, then change back to black       
                    } else if (emptyArr[0] !== emptyArr[1]) {
                        firstCard = emptyArr[0]
                        cards[i].style.backgroundColor = emptyArr[1]
                        emptyArr = []
                        setTimeout(() => {
                        firstCard = 'black'
                        cards[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black'                    
                          }, 1000)     
                        firstCard = ''
                     
                    }
                }
            })
                  
        }
    }
    
    const initializeGame = () => {
        shuffleArray(colors)
    
        for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            cards[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black'
        }
    
        handleCardClik()
    }
    
    startButton?.addEventListener('click', () => {
        initializeGame()   
    })
<!-- -->
    <body><section class="section-top sec-position">
        <div class="top-wrapper">
            <button class="start-btn js-start-btn">START</button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section section-main sec-position">
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <div class="top-row">
                <div class="card js-card"></div>
                <div class="card js-card"></div>
                <div class="card js-card"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bot-row">
                <div class="card js-card"></div>
                <div class="card js-card"></div>
                <div class="card js-card"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section-bot sec-position">
        <span class="win-message">WINNER LOSER</span>
    </section>
        <script src="/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
<!-- -->
    .sec-position {
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }
    
    .main-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 30px;
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 50px;
    
    }
    
    .card {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      gap: 30px;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .top-row {
      display: flex;
      gap: 30px;
    }
    
    .bot-row {
      display: flex;
      gap: 30px;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes to the handleCardClik function it should be working
the reason your code didn't work was majorly because of the settimeout function because you reset the firstcard variable before it runs and it runs after 1sec delay with the new value causing error I have simply cached the value in a variable called cachedFirstCard.
hope this helped

```
const handleCardClik = () => {
  // Variable to store first click card
  let firstCard
  for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i]?.addEventListener('click', () => {
      cards[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i]
      //push colors into an empty array and start comparing them when there are two colors
      emptyArr.push(colors[i])

      if (emptyArr.length === 2) {
        // if colors are same apply them to the cards, clear the array and the storing variable    
        if (emptyArr[0] === emptyArr[1]) {
          cards[i].style.backgroundColor = emptyArr[1]
          firstCard = ''
          emptyArr = []

          // if colors differ keep them for 1 second, then change back to black       
        } else if (emptyArr[0] !== emptyArr[1]) {
          cards[i].style.backgroundColor = emptyArr[1]
          emptyArr = []
          let cachedFirstCard = firstCard
          setTimeout(() => {
            cachedFirstCard.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
            cards[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black'
            firstCard = ''
          }, 1000)


        }
      }
      firstCard = cards[i]
    })

  }
}
```